# Comparator needed for an associative container

Tags: c++, templates, set, containers, comparator

I need a `std::set<std::pair<std::string, int>, Compare>` that compares two pairs according to their int values (in reverse order), if their int values are the same then according to their string values (in same order), **but if their strings are equal then the two pairs are considered equal** (regardless of their int values).  So the `Compare` class I came up with is:

```
struct Compare {
    bool operator()(const std::pair<std::string, int>& a, const std::pair<std::string, int>& b) const {
        if (a.first == b.first)
            return false;
        if (a.second > b.second)
            return true;
        if (a.second < b.second)
            return false;
        return a.first < b.first;   
    }
};
```

The test

```
std::set<std::pair<std::string, int>, Compare> s;
s.insert({"Apple", 3}); 
s.insert({"Apple", 5});
```

works fine (inserting only the first pair).  But

```
int main() {
    std::set<std::pair<std::string, int>, Compare> s;
    s.insert({"Ai", 14}); 
    s.insert({"Am", 14}); 
    s.insert({"F", 5}); 
    s.insert({"Apple", 3}); 
    s.insert({"Apple", 5}); 
}
```

shows both `{"Apple", 3}` and `{"Apple", 5}` being inserted, and I can't figure out why.  What is the logical error in my `Compare` class?  What is it supposed to be instead?  I considered using `std::map<std::string, int, Compare>` but in this case the comparator could only use the key type `std::string`, which won't suffice for my specs.

I also tried:

```
bool operator()(const std::pair<std::string, int>& a, const std::pair<std::string, int>& b) const {
    if (a.first < b.first || a.first > b.first) {
        if (a.second > b.second)
            return true;
        if (a.second < b.second)
            return false;
        return a.first < b.first;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and it still does not give the results I want.

Comment: Write out **carefully** what you want the result of the comparison to be when the strings are equal and when they are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After examining your requirements, I came to the conclusion that your criteria for comparing objects do not meet requirements of strictly week ordering.

Say you insert the following objects to the set:

```
std::pair<std::string, int> obj1 = {"F", 5};
std::pair<std::string, int> obj2 = {"Apple", 3};
std::pair<std::string, int> obj3 = {"Apple", 5};

s.insert{obj1); 
s.insert(obj2); 
s.insert(obj3);
```

`obj1` gets added since there is nothing else to compare with in the set.  `obj2` also gets added since it compare unequal to `obj1`. However. since `obj1.second > obj2.second`, the order of the objects in the set is:

```
obj1
obj2
```

Now, we come to insert `obj3`. `obj3 < obj1` evaluates to `true`. Hence, it gets inserted before `obj1`. The logic for inserting an item into the set is such that `obj3` never gets compares with `obj2`. Consequently, you end up with:

```
obj3
obj1
obj2
```

Comment: @ R Sahu   So forget using any STL container (and perhaps any comparator class at all) and write my own container (that implements a binary search tree)?

Comment: @prestokeys, Either that or use some wrapper code to control when an object gets inserted into the set.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how Compare in a `std::set` works. It is meant to provide an order from smallest to biggest. With your set you are trying to make 2 different kinds of comparisons.

You can order it by first int value, secondly string value. No problem.

But 2 elements in a set is considered equal if none if them compares smaller then the other one.

When you do your first example the 2 elements happens to be next to each other, so then the comparison function will be used on them and your `a.first == b.first` case triggers and none of them seems to be smaller then the other one so they are considered equal.

When you do your second attemp, by the time you insert `"Apple", 5` your set look like this.

```
Ai 14
Am 14
F 5
Apple 3
```

`Apple, 5` will here Compare smaller then `Am 14` and bigger then `F 5` so it will never be compared with `Apple 3` at all, but it will be inserted between the two elements it's bigger and smaller then. Since the `std::set` is expected to be sorted in order already the elements beyond are irrelevant as far as the `Compare` is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the first comparison, it's just wrong. Remove it and it works.

Comment: No, both  `{"Apple", 3}` and `{"Apple", 5}` are still being inserted (in both tests).  I need for two pairs to be considered equal if their strings are equal.